# How to manipulate data in excel with formula only once?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got an excel spread sheet with prices in it. I want to update the prices by adding x% price increase.
I tried to to it with an extra column to calculate the new price, copied the values of this formula to another column and then overwrote the old prices. Is there an easy way in excel, where I could directly enter a formula for selected data and it will update the data directly once?

Sorry if this is a bit off-topic but I found neither a stack-exchange page for excel, nor something relevant on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [ASAP Utilities](https://www.asap-utilities.com/) for all this kind of thing, and that has a tool under 'formulas' for 'apply a calculation to all selected cells'. Added to which there are loads of other handy tools in the add-in, I recommend it.
In your case, say you were doing a 5% price increase, you'd use the 'apply formula' tool and then input the formula `*105%` or similar.

Comment: thank you, I used this and it worked fine. I just hoped there is a native way in excel to do such a seemingly simple task... :D

Comment: @kinaeh you can make one in VBA code (that's what the ASAP pack uses), but it's not a built-in option as far as I'm aware. Do you want me to add a separate answer on how to code one yourself?

Comment: sorry, I'd have accepted it sooner, but the app din't let me. :D